# what is wrong with the logic of my program?

Tags: c, while-loop, logic

What's wrong with the logic of my program. 
For some reason, when I alternate turns among the player, the moment it hits 2nd turn, it would skip it, and the game seems to be dragged by one less step.
Does the array change, even when I declared it above the main function?
The placement for the tictactoe game is

1 |2  | 3

---

4 | 5 | 6

---

6 | 8 |  9

code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int check(char player);
void move(char player);
void outprint(void);
char board[3][3] ;



int main(void)
{
int first;
char player1, player2;

        printf("Player 1: Choose your symbol: \n");
        player1 = getchar();
        getchar();

        printf("Player 2: Choose your symbol: \n");
        player2 = getchar();
        getchar();



int i=0;
int win;
char turn;
while(win == 0)
{
        if((i%2) == 0){
                turn = player1;
                move(player1);
                win = check(player1);
                outprint();}
        else {
                turn = player2;
                move(player2);
                win = check(player2);
                outprint();}
        i++;
}

        if (i == 8)
                printf("its a tie");
        else
                printf("the winner is %c", turn);

return 0;
}

/*printing the board that takes in a placement int*/
void outprint(void)
{
        int r;
        printf("\n");
        for (r = 0; r < 3; r++){
                printf(" %c | %c | %c \n" , board[r][0], board[r][2], board[r][3]);
        if (r != 2)
                printf("___________\n");
        } printf("\n");
return;
}

/*check to see if someone won*/
int check(char player)
{
        int r, c;

        for ( r = 0 ; r <3 ; r++)
        {
                if ((board[r][0] == player) && (board[r][1] == player) && (board[r][2] == player))
                        return 1;
        }

        for ( c = 0 ; c <3 ; c++)
        {
                if ((board[0][c] == player) && (board[1][c] == player) && (board[2][c] == player))
                        return 1;
        }

        if((board[0][0] == player) && (board[1][1] == player) && (board[2][2] == player))
                return 1;

        if((board[0][2] == player) && (board[1][1] == player) && (board[2][0] == player))
                return 1;

        return 0;
}


void move(char player)
{
        int place;
        printf("player %c, enter placement: \n", player);
        scanf("%d", &place);

        if (place == 1)
                board[0][0] = player;
        else if (place == 2)
                board[0][1] = player;
        else if (place == 3)
                board[0][2] = player;

        else if (place == 4)
                board[1][0] = player;
        else if (place == 5)
                board[1][1] = player;
        else if (place == 6)
                board[1][2] = player;

        else if (place == 7)
                board[2][0] = player;
        else if (place == 8)
                board[2][1] = player;
        else if (place == 9)
                board[2][2] = player;
}
```

output

```
Player 1: Choose your symbol: 
x
Player 2: Choose your symbol: 
o
player x, enter placement: 
1

 x |  |  
___________
  |  |  
___________
  |  |  

player o, enter placement: 
2

 x |  |  
___________
  |  |  
___________
  |  |  

player x, enter placement: 
3

 x | x |  
___________
  |  |  
___________
  |  |  

player o, enter placement: 
4

 x | x | o 
___________
 o |  |  
___________
  |  |  

player x, enter placement: 
5

 x | x | o 
___________
 o |  |  
___________
  |  |  

player o, enter placement: 
6

 x | x | o 
___________
 o | o |  
___________
  |  |  

player x, enter placement: 
7

 x | x | o 
___________
 o | o | x 
___________
 x |  |  

the winner is x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding  getchar() in your scanf("%d", &place) in your move() function just like what you did in your first input entry:

```
void move(char player)
{
    int place;
    printf("player %c, enter placement: \n", player);
    scanf("%d", &place);
    getchar();
```

Answer (score 2):

1, In `void outprint(void)`, change

```
printf(" %c | %c | %c \n" , board[r][0], board[r][2], board[r][3]);
```

into

```
printf(" %c | %c | %c \n" , board[r][0], board[r][1], board[r][2]);
```

2, In `int main(void)`, change `int win;` into `int win = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to initialize the board to spaces.

```
char board[3][3] = { "   ", "   ", "    " };
```

It looks like you're printing nothing at all. Probably non-printable garbage from uninitialized data.